# editbox lostfocus fires on the wrong edittext box

Tags: android

I have a simple app with 2 edittext boxes. When input is typed into the 1st box one set of calculations are performed. If input is put into the other instead, a different set of calc's occurs.

So, if a number is typed into the first box etBox1, and the user leaves the box, the data from the first box is used to calculate a reesult and put it into the second box. If a number is typed into the second box etBox2, the data is used to calculate a value for the first box.

I tried:

```
final EditText etBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBox1) 
final EditText etBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBox2)

etBox1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
{ 
   @override
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean lostfocus)
   {
       if (lostFocus == true)
       { //do my calculations....}
```

This fires when the focus given to etBox1 instead of waiting for the box to loose focus. This crashes the app because the user hasn't had the chance to input a number into the box. Any ideas why this behaves as a "hasFocus" instead of a "lostFocus"? There is no documentation available on lostFocus at Android's site.

Comment: It may also be possible that the lostfocus is firing when the etBox1 gains focus, instead of looses focus.

Comment: I revised the method as follows and it worked: @Override  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)   { if (hasFocus==false)...do something

Answer (score 2):

In your question, you have this.

```
final EditText etBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBox1);
final EditText etBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBox1);
```

You are using the same ID when mapping the text boxes. I guess it should look like this:

```
final EditText etBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBox1);
final EditText etBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBox2);
```

Not to mention that you should also get a compilation error with your code, as you define `etBox1` two times...
(Unless this is only a typo in your question, and your code actually looks different...)

Comment: yes, i made a typo on the question, but not in the code. Sorry. Your version is how it is coded.

Comment: @Ted Betz; well, if that is the case you should at least edit your question so that the code you have there is correct according to what your real code looks like. Otherwise, people will probably see the same as me and not be able to help you with your real problem...

Comment: I revised the method as follows:

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html

onFocusChange is defined as public abstract void onFocusChange (View v, boolean hasFocus), so your boolean called lostFocus is named backwards and so confusing you, I'd recommend to change it to something like hasFocus.

now you should see that for if statement is the wrong way round, you should be checking if == false

Comment: Bugger just noticed your comment to your main question.